# Log not working (or seems to drop some lines)

Tags: android, android-service, android-logcat

EDIT: A more honed version of this question, with a good answer, is at: [Rather odd behaviour of Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001529/rather-odd-behaviour-of-log)

EDIT: The (bizarre) solution is reported as an answer below.

I have a service as part of an application which is running reasonably well, although there is an unusual bit of behaviour which I am trying to understand. To do this, I have been putting Log.d statement in various methods in classes to report state information at various points. All of these seem to be working (ie reporting the information) except those in the Service class. I know that the service is started because (a) it does something and (b) the threads it instantiates are issuing Log.d messages. However, even right at the start:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("SMS", "onCreate()");
    onCreateReal();
}
```

This log message never appears. What might I be doing wrong?

The manifest is as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.stuff.myapp"
android:versionCode="1111111"
android:versionName="0.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.stuff.myapp.Core"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="MyService"></service>

    <receiver android:name="com.stuff.myapp.WidgetInitiator">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_information"/>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name="com.stuff.myapp.ConfigWidgetActivity"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    </activity>
</application>
```

[EDIT: another observation]
As part of the app, I am calling a BroadcastReceiver class every 2 minutes (in testing). The class is stand alone (ie not inside any of the other classes). It does a Log.d every time it is called by AlarmManager. But only some of he Log calls make it to logcat. Again, suggestions welcome for what might be going on here.

[EDIT: I have corrected the above because the Threads it instantiates report Log calls correctly, but classes it instantiates don't.]

Comment: Any chance your tag filter is set to something other than "SMS"? Probably not but worth the shot!

Comment: Good thought, but I've searched through the unfiltered results and it isn't there ...

Comment: I have the same problem with you. No idea why it behaves like that

Comment: @nubhihi219 have you tries the answer below or the various things reported in the link at the top of the question?

Comment: Well I have figured out the answer. The reason is simple, I choose "Info" instead of "Verbose" so some Logs cannot be seen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done quite a lot of work resolving the underlying issue (see [Service being re-Created by AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435117/service-being-re-created-by-alarmmanager/15691054#15691054)), I still had this problem. The service still wasn't logging. For no reason I can explain, changing TAG from "SMS" to "SMservice" made it work. I can offer no good explanation other than it seemed to solve the problem.

And, to save you asking, if I change TAG back to "SMS" the messages disappear again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "tag:SMS" as filter in logcat.

Comment: I'm wondering why you say this - I've searched through the unfiltered results and it isn't there, will setting this filter show something that isn't in the unfiltered results?

Comment: It's easy to miss a debug log when logcat is spammed.

Comment: Ok, fair point, but not the issue here - do you know of any other reasons why Log.d might not happen (or get to the logcat)?

Comment: Sorry I do not. You could try some other messaging like System.out.println(); or a Toast