# Is it better to have one broadcast action or many for multiple listeners?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Following various challenges with android (in particular [Service being re-Created by AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435117/service-being-re-created-by-alarmmanager) and [Log not working (or seems to drop some lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409796/log-not-working-or-seems-to-drop-some-lines)), I am redesigning some of my code to work using Broadcast intents and Broadcast receivers. Now, suppose that you have a source of information and many listeners. The source of information wishes to send information to only one of the receivers at any point in time:

```
time=1: Broadcaster->Recevier 1
time=2: Broadcaster->Recevier 2
time=3: Broadcaster->Recevier 3
```

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. All the receivers can use the same action code, say "com.me.stuff.INFO_FROM_SOURCE". This means that the android system only has one extra possible broadcast type to handle but that the information goes to each receiver and each receiver has to decide if the information is for them.
2. Each receiver has its own code, say "com.me.stuff.INFO_FROM_SOURCE_TO_RECEIVER_X". This means that the android system has more possible broadcasts to handle but that only one receiver will have to handle the incoming broadcast.

Overall, which is the least load on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it the second way. br messages are meant to do one single thing. I suppose you could have one action with differences in the intent bundle, but that seems like an unnecessary step when you can filter by action, the way that its meant to to filtered.

you can have the same receiver filter for multiple actions, then on your onReceive, put in an if statement that checks all the possible actions.